# Does a random sample size produce a larger or smaller variance than a fixed sample size?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, sample-size

If you run two identical samples with the exception of the sample size where in both cases E(n)=1000, but in one the variance is 0 (ie. fixed sample size of 1000) and the other has non-zero variance, which estimate of the population total for some characteristic T will have a lower variance?

I hope I've explained this okay, if you need clarification then I'll try.

Thanks, Pat.

Comment: For the population total you need the population size, right? Instead, would it be fine to consider sample mean as an estimator of the population mean as an example?

Comment: By population total I mean, for example, suppose we sample 1000 people and record their weekly income. We may wish to estimate the total weekly income of our entire population. But, estimating the mean weekly income would be the same since we can then find the total using the mean.